# Using dd on Mac causes USB to become unreadable

Tags: macos, mac, usb, bootable-media

I'm trying to create a bootable Arch Linux USB installer from Mac OSX El Capitan.  I followed the tutorial on the Arch Linux Wiki, but when it "completes," I get a warning that `The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer` instead of getting a bootable USB media.

When finished, I get the following in `$ diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *8.0 GB     disk2
   1:                       0xEF                         41.9 MB    disk2s2
```

The steps I followed to get this result were:

```
# insert USB flash drive

$ diskutil list      # yields /dev/disk2

$ diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2       # okay

$ sudo dd if=/Users/user/Downloads/archlinux-2016.08.01-dual.iso of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m
```

I enter my password, the thing runs for a few minutes, then I get the above listed error message.  What have I missed?  The tutorial lists no other steps or conditions required so I'm quite lost.

Comment: You didn't miss anything.  The USB is not readable by OSX after you do this, but you don't need it to.  Just boot from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the image that dd writes to the USB is probably not a format that OSX can read. While OSX can read many mainstream file formats there are some that OSX do not. I suspect Arch will use one of the common to Linux boot image formats.

Reboot the computer you wish to install Arch on to and see if your USB drive is one of the bootable drives by pressing 'F2' (or sometimes one of the other keys: 'F12' or 'Delete') to display your boot options. You can then select the drive and boot to see your installer. **Do not allow the installer to continue if you are still using your Apple computer!!** The installer may overwrite the drive!

*** Edit ***

Apparently Arch doesn't have an 'installer' as such. Though I have little doubt there are some utilities able to manipulate the drive. Probably should be sure of the steps you are taking to install Arch in order to preserve your OSX installation.

Comment: No need to worry about an installer with Arch Linux, because there’s none. :D So it’s relatively unlikely you’ll accidentally nuke your drive.

Comment: Ah okay. Though it would still have utilities to partition/format the drive no?

It has been a while since I've played with an open source OS. Last one was Ubuntu 14.08, I think.

Comment: Yeah, you need those to install it (manually). But even Ubuntu lets you select how to partition the drive. Setups that overwrite the disk completely are present mostly in enterprise products, like XenServer and whatnot.